# Decode Base64 in SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, base64

I am getting an error on executing the decode query for a base 64 column.

Query:

```
select 
    convert(varchar(max), cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("t.SomeColumn"))', 'varbinary(max)')) as converted_64_column
from 
    SomeTable as t
```

Error:

> Msg 9344, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   XQuery [value()]: The SQL type 'text' is not supported with sql:column() and sql:variable().

Comment: t.SomeColumn type is defined as "text" in your sql server. This is not supported by XQuery. Change your type to nvarchar(max)

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to decode 'text' column? Please share the syntax if any one has.